# Android.mk file - including all source files in different folders and subfolders

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In writing an android .mk file, is there a short way to include many source files which are in different folders and subfolders? Like a loop or a code for iterating the folders? For example:

> folder1
>
> |---subfolder1.1
>
> ```
>       |---subfolder1.1.1
>
>                |---some cpp files
>
>       |--subfolder1.1.2
>
>            |--some cpp files
> ```
>
> folder2
>
> |---subfolder2.1
>
> ```
>       |--subfolder2.1.1
>
>            |--some cpp files
> ```
>
> |--(so on and so forth, another folders and subfolders and cpp
>   files)

I know I can use include `$(call all-subdir-makefiles)` for folders and subfolders but it will take too much time if I have so many folders, is there a better way? Like a loop for iterating through the folders? So I will have just one library for *folder1* and another for *folder2* and so on...

Answer (score 22):

```
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/**/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/**/**/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use ** wildcard to include files from all subdirectories:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(wildcard folder/**/*.cpp))
```