# How to write Android.mk file with source files in sub directories?

Tags: android-ndk

I have a structure like this:

```
folder1

      |--subfolder1

          |--.cpp files .h files

      |--other .cpp files
```

folder1 contains cpp files and 1 subfolder which also contains cpp files and head files

How will I write my Android.mk file so that all the source files, including those inside subfolder1 will be included during compilation?

i tried

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/\*/\*.*) $(wildcard *.*)
```

but it does not work, it didnt include the source files which are inside the subdirectories

Comment: This is already solved. How can I flag this as solved? or closed this thread? Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android.mk file - including all source files in different folders and subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970082/android-mk-file-including-all-source-files-in-different-folders-and-subfolders)

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*/*.cpp)
```

Comment: give a reason why, not just an answer.

Comment: $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*/*.cpp)  will put all files that ends will .cpp and found in folders : $(LOCAL_PATH)/*/    ;

Answer (score 4):

this may help.
quote:

> If you want to define Android.mk files in sub-directories, you should
> include them explicitly in your top-level Android.mk. There is even
> a helper function to do that, i.e. use:
>
> include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
>
> This will include all Android.mk files in sub-directories of the current build file's path.

copied from android-ndk-r8d doc.

that means you should write a Android.mk file to describe your .cpp in each of your subdir, and write a top-level Android.mk to include them by "include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)"

now it may like this:

```
|-jni

|----Android.mk (top level one)

|--------subfolder1

|------------Android.mk (to describe your a.cpp)

|------------a.cpp/a.h

|----other .cpp/.h files
```