# Android.mk How to use wildcard to include all .cpp files?

Tags: android, eclipse, makefile, cocos2d-x

This is my directory structure...

```
> Classes [dir]
> ---subdir1
> ------ some .cpp and .h files
> ---subdir2
> ------ some .cpp and .h files
> ---more .cpp and .h files
> ---Android.mk
```

This is the code for Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_logic_static

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame_logic

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AppDelegate.cpp \
                   HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := png_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += xml2_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += jpeg_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := cocosdenshion_shared

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/modules/libpng)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/modules/libxml2)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/modules/libjpeg)
```

Can anyone post the correct code (complete if possible) for Android.mk so all .cpp will be compiled in Class directory? Thanks!

Note: Trying to develop cocos2d-x Android with Eclipse
More notes: I already tried these to no avail:

> [Android.mk file - including all source files in different folders and
>   subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970082/android-mk-file-including-all-source-files-in-different-folders-and-subfolders) [How to write android.mk file with source files in
>   subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971390/how-to-write-android-mk-file-with-source-files-in-subdirectories) [Android.mk, include all cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980284/android-mk-include-all-cpp-files)